# Error receiving while generating excel using servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-3.0

I have created a piece of code for generating and downloading an excel file in servlet. The code is provided below:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String act = request.getParameter("act").toLowerCase();
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("sqleditor.jsp");

    try {
        if(act.equalsIgnoreCase("exec")) {
            String uqry = request.getParameter("isql");
            if ( !uqry.isEmpty() ) {
                qp = new queryProcessor(uqry);
                mp = qp.getResultSet();
                request.setAttribute("result",mp);
                rd.forward(request, response);
            } else {
                ERROR_MSG = "Please enter a query";
                request.setAttribute("errormsg", ERROR_MSG);
                rd.forward(request, response);
            }
        } else if (act.equalsIgnoreCase("excel")) {
            String uqry = request.getParameter("isql");
            if ( !uqry.isEmpty() ) {
                try {
                    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + FILENAME + "\"");
                    initExcelfile(response.getOutputStream());
                } catch (Exception evar1) {
                    request.setAttribute("errormsg", evar1.getMessage());
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                }

                System.out.println("File downloaded at client successfully");
            }
        }
    } catch (AppException evar2) {
        request.setAttribute("errormsg", evar2.getmessage());
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } catch (SQLException evar3) {
        request.setAttribute("errormsg", evar3.getMessage());
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } catch (NullPointerException evar4) {
        request.setAttribute("errormsg", evar4.getMessage());
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException evar5) {
        request.setAttribute("errormsg", evar5.getMessage());
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception evar6) {
        request.setAttribute("errormsg", evar6.getMessage());
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}

private void initExcelfile(ServletOutputStream outputStream) {

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Datatypes");

    Object[][] datatypes = {
            {"Datatype", "Type", "Size(in bytes)"},
            {"int", "Primitive", 2},
            {"float", "Primitive", 4},
            {"double", "Primitive", 8},
            {"char", "Primitive", 1},
            {"String", "Non-Primitive", "No fixed size"}
    };

    int rowNum = 0;
    System.out.println("Creating excel");

    for (Object[] datatype : datatypes) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
        int colNum = 0;
        for (Object field : datatype) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
            if (field instanceof String) {
                cell.setCellValue((String) field);
            } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Workbook Created");

    try {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But when I move the initExcelfile() method to a separate class file and invoke the method from there I receive the below error:

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-4) UT005023: Exception handling request to /sqle/sqleditor.jsp: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010006: Cannot call getWriter(), getOutputStream() already called
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:245)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:147)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:111)
    at com.sqle.RequestController.doPost(RequestController.java:84)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010006: Cannot call getWriter(), getOutputStream() already called
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.getWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:355)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:112)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:183)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:121)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.jsp.sqleditor_jsp._jspService(sqleditor_jsp.java:196)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:402)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:346)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:274)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:209)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:221)
    ... 42 more
```

Could you please let me know what I am missing here due to which I am encountering this error.

Comment: Try to print the stack trace of the exception `evar1` .

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stacktrace, it looks like you are first doing this:

```
  initExcelfile(response.getOutputStream())
```

which is throwing an exception.  Then in the exception handler you appear to be trying to redirect to a JSP to produce an error message.  Unfortunately, that is failing because:

- the JSP is going to call `getWriter()` on the response object to find the place to send its output,
- you have already called `getOutputStream()` on the response object, and
- you cannot call both `getWriter()` and `getOutputStream()` on the same `Response` object ... or you will get an `IllegalStateException`!

If you are going to write your spreadsheet directly to the output, you CANNOT redirect to a JSP in the event of failure.  Even if the servlet framework allowed it (it doesn't!), you would be liable to get a partial spreadsheet with an error page tacked on the end.  The user's web browser wouldn't be able to make sense of that.

There are two alternatives:

1. Get rid of that attempted redirect in the case where you get an exception while generating the spreadsheet.
2. Keep the redirect, but change your code so that you prepare and buffer the spreadsheet.  Only open the response output stream *after* you have successfully generated the spreadsheet.

There is also the question of what is causing the exception in the first place.  There are no obvious clues that I can see, so you will need to debug that yourself.  (For example, you could attach a debugger and set a breakpoint in the exception handler, and look at the caught exception's class, message and callstack.)